# Polynomial Regression using keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, regression

hi i am new to keras and i just wanted to know are ann's good for polynomial regression tasks or we shuold just 
use sklearn for exmaple i write this script

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential


x=np.arange(1, 100)
y=x**2

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=200, activation = 'relu',input_dim=1))
model.add(Dense(units=200, activation= 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001))

model.fit(x, y,epochs=2000)
```

but after testing it on some of numbers i didn't get good result like :

```
model.predict([300])
array([[3360.9023]], dtype=float32)
```

is there any problem in my code or i just shouldn't use ann's for polynomial regressions.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100 percent sure, but I think that the reason you are getting such bad predictions is because you did not scale your data. Artificial neural networks are extremely computationally intensive, and thus, scaling is a must. Scale your data as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential


x=np.arange(1, 100)
y=x**2

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_x = StandardScaler()
x = sc_x.fit_transform(x)
sc_y = StandardScaler()
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=5, activation = 'relu',input_dim=1))
model.add(Dense(units=5, activation= 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001))

model.fit(x, y,epochs=75, batch_size=10)

prediction = sc_y.inverse_transform(model.predict(sc_x.transform([300])))
print(prediction)
```

Note that I changed the number of epochs from 2000 to 75. This is because 2000 epochs is way to high for a neural network, and it requires lots of time to train. Your X dataset contains only 100 values, so the maximum number of epochs I would suggest is 75.

Furthermore, I also changed the number of neurons in each hidden layer from 200 to 5. This is because 200 neurons is far to many for most datasets, let alone a small dataset of length 100.

These changes should ensure that your neural network produces more accurate predictions.

Hope that helped.